Storybook v7 Cannot read property of undefined (ComponentHoc)
The code exports a constant containing the result of executing the ComponentHoc function. When I try to reflect a component in story, I get an error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ComponentHoc')
    at Module.ComponentHoc (http://localhost:6006/components-Feedback-stories-Feedback-stories.iframe.bundle.js:4285:104)
    at ./src/common/components/FloatingButton/styled.tsx (http://localhost:6006/components-Feedback-stories-Feedback-stories.iframe.bundle.js:2161:79)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:298:21)
    at ./src/common/components/FloatingButton/index.tsx (http://localhost:6006/components-Feedback-stories-Feedback-stories.iframe.bundle.js:1761:65)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:298:21)
    at ./src/common/components/index.ts (http://localhost:6006/components-Feedback-stories-Feedback-stories.iframe.bundle.js:4127:73)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:28:33)
    at fn (http://localhost:6006/runtime~main.iframe.bundle.js:298:21)

the place where it crashed looks like
export const FloatingButtonWrapperWithTooltip = TooltipHoc(FloatingButtonWrapper);

I tried to check reexports, but no results. All of them looks good.

my bad. It was imports mistake
